# AWS Account Migration using DMS (Data Migration Service)

Tags: amazon-web-services, migration, devops, database-migration, dms

We are planning to a cross account migration using DMS, where we would need to do migration of data from one aws account to another, in which the data from the source account will just be added to the target account. And the data in the target account will not be affected.

After the migration. The data in the target account should look like this:

Target account = data from source account + data in target account

Note: both accounts have existing data

Would someone be able to provide some steps on how to do this?

I tried manually adding the data from source to target, but this may not be a reliable way

Comment: What issue do you face? In DMS you can choose tables based on the schema, so there is no need to add all the tables manually (use * for tables in your schema). If you want to keep the data in destination tables, choose "do nothing" as a database preparation step (these could be drop tables, truncate, do nothing)

Comment: We did vpc peering for the connection of the two accounts, but when I modified the route of the vpc to asd the CIDR of the target account, an error regarding overlapping CIDR occurs. I can't change the cidr due to some dependencies

Comment: If you have overlapping CIDR, you can't do VPC peering. What you could do, although more expensive, is that you could create a new DB in that account, in a separate VPC. You do a peering between new VPC and source account. DMS migrate data to this new DB. Second DMS migrates data to the destination DB. If it is one-time work, that's ok, if it's ongoing, it would be expensive